# Проблема с освещением pointlight(unity 2d)

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

Добрый день.

У меня есть 2d спрайты, у них материал с шейдером `sprites/diffuse`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сцене прикреплен *pointlght*. Когда там выбран белый свет, то видна сфера света:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда меняю цвет, допустим на красный, то эта сфера пропадает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы было как в 1 варианте, но чтоб свет был красного цвета?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу сделать предположение что у вас текстуры спрайтов в RGB почти не содержат красного и из-за этого цвет источника красный на них не оказывает воздействия. Попробуйте поменять источник скажем на синий, если я прав то ваша сцена должна нормально загореться.